# How to randomise sampling of a matrix using different distributions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, grid-search, probability-distribution

I have a 3x3 matrix that looks like this:

`input_df`

```
       C1    C2    C3
Row1   0     5     10        
Row2   5     10    11        
Row3   100   0     243
```

The actual data frame is 50x10, I'm using a 3x3 for demonstration purposes. I'm running an optimization experiment where I am trying to generate randomized versions `input_df` where I am can tune the 'parameters' of the randomness.

For e.g, to create `random1_df`, I have first sample the rows, then the columns

`random1_df`

```
       C1    C3    C2  
Row2   5     11    5    
Row3   100   243   10
Row1   0     10    243
```

I want to be able to experiment with the different sampling parameters of randomness, i.e want to use a uniform distribution, then a gaussian distribution etc

`Uniform`

```
random1_df = input_df.sample(frac=1, axis=0).sample(frac=1, axis=1)
```

`Normal Distribution`

```
M = [[0,5,10],[100,243,10],[0,10,243]]
random1_df = np.random.choice(M,n=3,replace=True)
```

1. Is this correct?
2. How I do carry out this process for a 50x10 matrix?

Comment: What you want is unclear. You want shuffling, which is uniform. It would make sense to define a distribution for **sampling** from a continuous variable, which is not what you're doing here. What you can do with `sample` is to add weights, but with `frac=1` and the default `replace=False`, this is useless.

Comment: Please see my attempt at a normal distribution. Yes, what you said is exactly what I am after. I'm unsure how to sample from a continuous variable or how to add weights to ```sample```

Comment: As I said above, what are you really trying to do? How would you expect the output to be different with a "gaussian distribution"?

Comment: IIUC, sample the indexes, then slice into the values with the sampled indexes. But like others commented, that's sampling, not shuffling.

Comment: @mozway please see my attempt for a random sampling. How I do carry out this process for a 50x10 matrix?

Comment: @QuangHoang same question for you ^ :)

Comment: The two operations for `Uniform` and `Normal distribution` are still different. `Uniform` is shuffling (`replace=False` when `frac=1`); `Normal Distribution` is sampling with repetition, and only for rows. As for the question *Is this correct*, we're trying to understand what exactly you're trying to do because examples are not consistent. Q2. Both of them carries over to 50x10 just fine/

Comment: @QuangHoang yes that is correct, `Uniform` is shuffling (replace=False when frac=1). How do I carry out`Normal Distribution` which is sampling with repetition, for rows and columns?